# $\int_{-1}^{1} (3^x+3^{-x}) \tan{x}dx$, how do I solve this integral.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{-1}^{1} (3^x+3^{-x}) \tan{x}dx$$

Can someone give me at least an idea or a hint to solve this integral.
I know that the function is odd and that an odd integral from -a to a is equal to 0. I try to find another way to solve it.

Comment: The way you already know requires verifying $\int_0^1(3^x+3^{-x})\tan xdx$ converges, but that's easy as the integrand is between $0$ and $\tfrac{10}{3}\tan1$.

Comment: So you want to find $\int 3^x \tan x dx$. If you let $I(k) = \int 3^x \tan^k x dx$ for natural $k$, then you can find a relation between $I(k)$ and $I(k+1)$ using integration by parts on $I(k)$. Dunno if this helps in any way though.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} (3^x+3^{-x}) \tan{x}dx\overset{x\to -x} = -I=0$$

Comment: That is the proof using "odd function".

Answer (score 1):

Hint-
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} (3^x+3^{-x}) \tan{x}dx$$
Also you may be aware that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$$
So following the above property we can write
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} (3^{-x}+3^{x}) -\tan{x}dx$$
So $$I+I = 0$$
$$I=0$$
EDIT- If you don't want to directly use the property then you can prove the property and use it, like this
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} (3^x+3^{-x}) \tan{x}dx$$
Put $-1+1-x=t$
$-dx=dt$
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} (3^{-t}+3^t) -\tan{t}dx$$
And we also know that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$$
So that's the proof if you want to do it this way.